# Unable to load class 'net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeIntegrationUnavailableException'

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Soy nuevo con Android Studio y al iniciar un nuevo proyecto me aparece el error:

> Unable to load class 'net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeIntegrationUnavailableException'.

Intenté buscando en internet pero ni en los foros en inglés encuentro la solución, ni con chatgpt ya que solo tiene conocimiento hasta versiones anteriores de AndroidStudio.